# Can I get UIWebView to present the same keyboard for an email input as Safari does?

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I have noticed that my app, which uses a UIWebView to present web content uses a different keyboard when the user selects an input field which has the HTML5 type "email" than Safari does.  The issue is that one of the web pages my app is displaying (I don't control the web page content) requires a backslash in this field.  The keyboard that Safari displays for this web site has a backslash key while the one that is displayed from UIWebView doesn't.

Here's what Safari uses for symbols:

[image]

And this is what UIWebView uses:

[image]

Is there any way to get UIWebView to use the same keyboard as Safari for email input fields?  Why are they different?

Answer (score 0):

Do you test with same html source? The Safari keyboard you're showing does not look like an email keyboard (lacks @).

Comment: These screen shots are of the same HTML source.  I am looking at the "symbols" keyboard (tap the "123" key, then tap the "#+=" key).